# How to use X and Y positions of a Sprite for "Fling" physics in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, phaser-framework, matter.js

I am making a game using Phaser 3, specifically the Matter physics engine. I am trying to follow this tutorial on fling physics https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2019/03/08/fling-unity-game-built-in-html5-with-phaser-and-matter-js-updated-with-the-latest-constraints-tweaks-fly-through-the-screen-with-your-ninja-rope/

```
let game;
let gameOptions = {
    gravity: 1,
    constraintSpeed: 2,
    hookSpeed: 20,
    ropeTolerance: 6
};
const BALL = 1;
const HOOK = 2;

window.onload = function() {

    let gameConfig = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        scale: {
            mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
            autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
            parent: "thegame",
            width: 1200,
            height: 750
        },
        scene: playGame,
        physics: {
            default: "matter",
            matter: {
                gravity: {
                    y: gameOptions.gravity
                },
                debug: true
            }
        }
    }
    game = new Phaser.Game(gameConfig);
    window.focus();
};
class playGame extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor(){
        super("PlayGame");
    }
    preload() {
        //Load background image
        this.load.image('background', 'images/background.png');

        this.load.atlas('sheet', 'assets/spiderTP.png', 'assets/spiderTP.json');
        this.load.json('shapes', 'assets/spritesPE.json');
    }
    create() {
        //Place background image
        let background = this.add.image(600, 375, 'background');

        //Update the game at 30Hz
        this.matter.world.update30Hz();

        //Get hitboxes
        var shapes = this.cache.json.get('shapes');

        //Set boundaries for physics
        this.matter.world.setBounds(0, 0, game.config.width, 800);

        //Player
        this.hero = this.matter.add.sprite(600, 500, 'sheet', '0001', {shape: shapes.s0001})
        this.hero.label = BALL;
        this.hook = null;

        //Fire the hook
        this.input.on("pointerdown", this.fireHook, this);

        this.rope = null;

        //Listen for collisions with the hook
        this.matter.world.on("collisionstart", function(e, b1, b2){
            if((b1.label == HOOK || b2.label == HOOK) && !this.rope) {
                Phaser.Physics.Matter.Matter.Body.setStatic(this.hook, true);
                let distance = Phaser.Math.Distance.Between(this.hero.body.position.x, this.hero.body.position.y, this.hook.position.x, this.hook.position.y);

                if (distance > gameOptions.heroSize * 2) {
                    this.rope = this.matter.add.constraint(this.hero, this.hook, distance, 0.1);
                }
            }
        }, this);
    }

    fireHook(e) {
        if(this.hook) {
            this.releaseHook();
        }
        else {
            let angle = Phaser.Math.Angle.Between(this.hero.body.position.x, this.hero.body.position.y, e.position.x, e.position.y);

            this.hook = this.matter.add.rectangle(this.hero.body.position.x + 40 * Math.cos(angle), this.hero.body.position.y + 40 * Math.sin(angle), 10, 10);
            this.hook.label = HOOK;

            Phaser.Physics.Matter.Matter.Body.setVelocity(this.hook, {
                x: gameOptions.hookSpeed * Math.cos(angle),
                y: gameOptions.hookSpeed * Math.sin(angle)
            });
        }
    }

    releaseHook() {
        if(this.rope) {
            this.matter.world.removeConstraint(this.rope);
            this.rope = null;
        }
        if(this.hook){
            this.matter.world.remove(this.hook);
            this.hook = null;
        };
    }
    update() {
        // is there a constraint? Shrink it
        if(this.rope){
            this.rope.length -= gameOptions.constraintSpeed;
            let hookPosition = this.hook.position;
            let distance = Phaser.Math.Distance.Between(hookPosition.x, hookPosition.y, this.hero.body.position.x, this.hero.body.position.y);
            if(distance - this.rope.length > gameOptions.ropeTolerance){
                this.rope.length = distance;
            }
            this.rope.length = Math.max(this.rope.length, gameOptions.heroSize * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT- I am getting closer. Now there are no errors, however, no ropes are shot

Comment: What do you mean by "no ropes are shot"? I'll need more context & explanation to help you debug.

Comment: @ManuelAbascal the block or “hook” is shot and sticks, however, the rope that should attack between the player and the hook, does not appear. Does that make more sense

Comment: I replied to you in the chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the **`sprite`** position X & Y like so:

```
hero.body.position.x
hero.body.position.y
```

Comment: Still no luck. I am still getting ```game.js:88 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
    at playGame.fireHook (game.js:88)
    at initialize.h.emit (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.processDownEvents (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.update (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.updateInputPlugins (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.queueMouseDown (phaser.min.js:1)
    at HTMLCanvasElement.onMouseDown (phaser.min.js:1)```

Comment: @RobertSmith I'm at work right now, if you put it in your github repo, I could take a look tonight. Let me know...

Comment: I can do that. I will let you know as soon as I update it. Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/roberto257/Phaser-Spiderman/tree/master/Spider-Man%20Game this is the repo. The game.js is the code I was trying to copy and implement with a sprite, while the spiderman_game.js is the current code. Thanks again

Comment: I am not meaning to bother, just trying to keep you updated. Now, my sprite shoots the ball, but does not shoot a rope behind it. There are no errors displaying in the current code in the repo.

Comment: You can use this chat room to give me all the details that you think are needed: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202230/discussion-on-how-to-use-x-and-y-positions-of-a-sprite-for-fling-physics-in-pha

Comment: I sent you a message from today :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at **this.hero**.

*"Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"* means that the property stated before the x in **this.hero.position.x** is not found, and probably does not exist in its parent property. In this case, **this.hero** does not contain the **position** property.

We can see the property of **this.hero** by typing it in the console while the code is running:

[image: Properties of this.hero]

You can see that **position** does not exist as an accessible property.

In your case, you need to use the **body** property.

[image]

This property includes the **position** property that includes the x and y coordinates.

So as a conclusion, access the x and y coordinates of **this.hook** with the following lines:

```js
this.hero.body.position.x
this.hero.body.position.y
```

(this answer is in response to the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58811485/1) of this question)

Comment: still not luck. I am still getting ```game.js:88 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
    at playGame.fireHook (game.js:88)
    at initialize.h.emit (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.processDownEvents (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.update (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.updateInputPlugins (phaser.min.js:1)
    at initialize.queueMouseDown (phaser.min.js:1)
    at HTMLCanvasElement.onMouseDown (phaser.min.js:1)```

Comment: Add in console.log(this.hero) somewhere, and see if this.hero has a body property, and a position property within that.